# Referencing array of arrays in while loop

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying to reference and set variables equal to specific elements within an array of arrays, shown here :

`student = [["Last", "Doofus"], ["First", "Douglas"], ["Exam", "75"], ["Homework", "65"], ["Attendance", "60"]]`

The ultimate goal is to find out the final grade based on these grades. for example, here is my code :

```
while line = gets
  examRaw = student[2][1].to_i
  hwRaw = student[3][1].to_i
  exam = (examRaw * 0.5) / 100
  hw = (hwRaw * 0.3) / 100
  final = exam + hw
  puts "Final Numeric Grade = " + final
end
```

I am receiving an error on the `examRaw` line. The error I am receiving is :

```
`<main>': undefined method [] for #<Enumerator:0x000000021059d0> (NoMethodError)`.
```

I have tested this in irb with the same exact array and it seems to have no problem finding the numbers that I need to be referenced. For example :

```
irb(main):016:0> student[2][1].to_i
=> 75
```

What is causing the error?

Comment: Unrelated, but the `puts` line should be more like `puts "Final Numeric Grade = #{final}"`. What's the point of the `while` loop in the first place?

Comment: is this all of the code? I don't see an enumerator anywhere in here...

Comment: Do you at some point have `student = student.to_enum`?